# How to lazy load html div tags using intersection-observer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, intersection-observer

Is it possible to lazy-load the entire div-tag using Intersection Observer API?

I have lazy loaded images using the intersection observer api approach. Not sure how to do it for html elements.

Comment: You should have all the details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Instead of setting img src, load the html for the div tags. For example, `img.attr('src', lazy_src)` would be replaced by `div.load(div_content_url)`. Note that some browsers require the intersected elements such as the div to have non-zero width and height, so you may need add a border to the divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can lazy load content into `divs`. The example below simply uses `html()` to populate the div with a random string on intersect. If the content you want is a separate html page, you could use `load()` instead.

```js
function lazyDivs() {
  let lis = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("div.lazy")),
    items = ["Aruba", "Jamaica", "Bermuda", "Bahama", "Key Largo", "Montego"];

  if (!lis.length) {
    //do nothing
  } else if ("IntersectionObserver" in window) {
    let o = new IntersectionObserver(function(es, obs) {
      es.forEach(function(e) {
        if (e.isIntersecting) {
          let li = $(e.target);
          li.html(items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)]);
          //li.load('/path/to/html/fragment'); //option to load content from a separate page
          li.removeClass("lazy");
          o.unobserve(e.target);
        }
      });
    });
    lis.forEach(function(li) {
      o.observe(li);
    });
  } else {
    lis.forEach(function(li) {
      let l = $(li);
      l.html(items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)]);
      //l.load('/path/to/html/fragment'); //option to load content from a separate page
      l.removeClass("lazy");
    });
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  lazyDivs();
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="lazy"></div>
  <div class="lazy"></div>
  <div class="lazy"></div>
  <div class="lazy"></div>
  <div class="lazy"></div>
  <div class="lazy"></div>
  <div class="lazy"></div>
  <div class="lazy"></div>
  <div class="lazy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```